# Como desencriptar datos de un array codeigniter3

Tags: php, mvc, codeigniter-3

Sucede que encripte unos registros con la libreria 'encryption' antes de guardarlos, hasta ahi, todo bien.

hago la consulta y todo bien los datos llegan encryptados .

Lo que Deseo es quitar la encriptacion en el controlador, antes de meterlos en el array y pasarlos a la vista.

**(Las tarjetas vienen encriptadas desde la base de datos)**

```
public function card_list()
{

  $id_user    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
  $this->db->where('id_user', $id_user);
  $query = $this->db->get("cards");


  $data = [];


  foreach($query->result() as $r) {

       $data[] = array(


            $r->card_owner,
            $r->card_number,
            $r->card_mm,
             $r->card_aa,
            $r->card_tag,


       );
  }



}
```

Comment: Hola, puedes utilizar `$this->encryption->decrypt($texto_encriptado);` para mas informacion puedes ver este [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html) . Saludos.

Comment: Si, lo que no se es como desencriptar los datos y volver a meterlos en el array para pasarlos a la vista

Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @MaicolRomero te acaban de responder eso, para desencriptar sería algo asi: `$this->encryption->decrypt($r->card_owner)`  y para retornar el array simplemente realiza el `return $data;` al final de la función, ahora enviarlos a tu vista va a depender de donde estés llamando a esta función

Answer (score 1):

Bueno te coloco un poco más amplia mi respuesta, para desencriptar la data y enviarla a la vista seria algo más o menos así

```
<?php
class Base extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){

        $data = [
            'tarjeta'   =>  $this->card_list()
        ];

        $this->load->view('vista',$data);//Aqui pasamos la data de la funcion a la vista
    }


    public function card_list()
    {

        $id_user    = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $this->db->where('id_user', $id_user);
        $query = $this->db->get("cards");


        $data = [];


        foreach($query->result() as $r) {

            $data[] = array(
                    $this->encryption->decrypt($r->card_owner),
                    $this->encryption->decrypt($r->card_number),
                    $this->encryption->decrypt($r->card_mm),
                    $this->encryption->decrypt($r->card_aa),
                    $this->encryption->decrypt($r->card_tag),
            );
        }

        return $data;

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias hermano por tu ayuda, voy a implementar el codigo y te aviso que tal salio , Gracias

Comment: Me da un error, por favor podria echarme un avento a traves de team viewer ?

Comment: @MaicolRomero que error te da??? dime y vemos si vale la pena el esfuerzo, estamos para ayudarnos. Saludos

Comment: Este es el error  :  A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: card/list.php

Line Number: 105

Backtrace:

File: C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\PHP7\htdocs\pago3\application\views\myaccount\card\list.php
Line: 105
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\PHP7\htdocs\pago3\application\controllers\myaccount\card.php
Line: 185
Function: view

File: C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\PHP7\htdocs\pago3\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: ok @MaicolRomero pero que línea de código se encuentra en la ´linea 105 de ese archivo, solo con ver el error esta complicado, muestra la línea a ver

Comment: Estimado Carlos, puede usted brindarme 5 minutos de su aprecido tiempo en una asistencia a través de team viewer, así verifica usted mismo. 

De lo contrario estaria poniendo los códigos aquí

Comment: Esta es la vista cuando intento imprimir los datos aqui 



foreach ($card_list as  $r) { 



               
Linea del error -->                    echo $r->card_owner;   








                    }  ?>

Comment: @MaicolRomero ok dame los datos del team

Comment: 178 876 904   

clave   4369

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/Michael3817